# asSql() method is removed from ClientPreparedStatement (mysql-connector-java and mysql-connector-j)

Tags: java, mysql-connector

In the mysql-connector-java library, ClientPreparedStatement had a public method called asSql() which was very helpful to me, but it was removed in April of this year, and that code carried over to the mysql-connector-j project. I used it in a QueryInterceptor which allowed me to give a meaningful name to AWS X-ray subsegments. By naming each subsegment using the beginning of each query, I can quickly narrow down any long-running queries in my AWS lambda function by looking at the X-ray trace. Today I was trying to upgrade my application to mysql-connector-j, or at least the latest version of mysql-connector-java, but I found this asSql() method no longer exists on ClientPreparedStatement.

I walked back through the versions of mysql-connector-java and found that the function was there in the 8.0.28 jar (Jan 17, 2022) but removed in 8.0.29 (Apr 25, 2022). It was never marked deprecated that I could find.

I found that by calling ClientPreparedStatement.toString(), I got the same query back, but prepended by "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: " - which of course I could strip off but then I'm tightly coupling my app to something which may change in a future version. So I'd rather not do this.

Is there another way to get asSql() functionality from a ClientPreparedStatement?

Comment: I tracked this down to the commit on the github mysql-connector-j project, but I don't seem to have permission to open an issue on the project. The method was removed on Jan 17, 2022 by soklakov in commit 4c98c11eb93dd56c01b9f5945f0e16137c585a39:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/commit/4c98c11eb93dd56c01b9f5945f0e16137c585a39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Filipe Silva on the mysql forum, the better solution is to use the sql parameter supplied in the preProcess() interface of the QueryInterceptor. I have switched to using that, and all works without using query.asSql().

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but I think the answer is "If you don't stick to the published JDBC APIs all bets are off." You are expecting an internal MySQL-specific method to be supported by all releases of the MySQL JDBC driver, but that simply isn't a requirement binding the people supplying the driver.

I mean, yeah, it would be nice if they would retain the method for you, but you're going to have to negotiate with them about reverting that change, and IME it probably isn't going to happen.

It looks like using the toString() method is probably your best bet. It is NOT guaranteed to keep working any particular way, but at least it works...

Comment: Fair point Tod.